# Changing from Android WebView to Microsoft Edge

Tags: android, webview, webview2

I have some Androids apps, that use android.webkit.WebView to display some websites with Chromium as rendering engine. Now my company has decided to only use Microsoft Products, which sadly also includes my apps and i have to use Microsoft Edge here, too (while still using the Android device).

i have done some googleing and found the Microsoft Edge WebView2. But as far as i have seen, this is only for Windows apps and not available for Android. Did i maybe miss something?

Alternatively, can i change the rendering engine from android.webkit.WebView to use microsoft edge?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

WebView2 doesn't currently support Android and it is also not currently on the [WebView2 roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/roadmap). You might check if Microsoft Edge on Android supports Chrome Custom Tabs or Trusted Web Activities if those controls will work for your scenario.